# How make Mapper to take inputs from two different files having common column?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Want to find the "list of Airlines" having zero "stoppages" using MapReduce.

"Airport Name" is given in one file and their "stoppages" are present in other file. Column field among these two file is "Airport ID"

First cvs file contained these fields:

```
   Airline (IATA) 
    Airline ID 
    Source airport
    Source airport ID 
    Destination airport
    Destination airport ID 
    Codeshare 
    stoppages
    Equipment
```

And file-2 contain fields are

```
Airline ID
Airline Name
Alias airline
IATA code
ICAO
Callsign
Country/territory
Active
```

how to handle this situation ? Please explain in details.

Comment: I don't see "Airline Name" in any file and I do not understand the sentence: "If data Structure of both these file are same and could able to take same input", please rewrite it in a readable way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the processing of two data sets using Joins in map-reduce. Looks like your second file is small as compared to the first one and can be loaded in memory. Load the 2nd file using DistributedCache API and use map side-join concept  in mappper code.

Comment: HI Ishan, are you taking about loading data in hive database and later execute join query to retrieve the desire data ....?  please brief me in details